# reading excel file from document library and insert into SharePoint list using c# version of SharePoint 2007

Tags: sharepoint

I am trying to read excel file from document library and insert into list.

Can any one help me in this

Thanks,
Jyoshi

Comment: Can you share the code you've written so far?

Comment: In event receiver getting the spfile objfile-properties.listitem.file

Comment: I need to know how to rea the document column values and push into list